# R type provider and Ggplot2

Tags: r, f#, type-providers

Has anyone used both ?
I would not mind seeing a short example to quickstart.

I can run the example.fsx script : the acf function side effects to a graph showing up.

But I dont know how to have a ggplot graphic appear.

```
open RProvider.ggplot2
open RProvider.utils

R.setwd @"C:/code/pp/Datasets/output/Kaggle/dontgetkicked"
let f = R.read_csv("measure_DNGtraining.csv")
R.qplot("erase_rate", "components",f)
```

That yields to a

```
val it : SymbolicExpression =
  RDotNet.SymbolicExpression {Engine = RDotNet.REngine;
                              IsClosed = false;
                              IsInvalid = false;
                              IsProtected = true;
                              Type = List;}
```

I am reading the instruction but if anyone has a snippet handy...

Comment: PS: I can share a more complete sample later in the evening ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need to pass the resulting expression to `R.print`:

```
R.qplot("erase_rate", "components",f)
|> R.print
```

The problem with using ggplot2 through the F# type provider is that the ggplot2 library is a bit too clever. I was playing with this for a while and it seems that it works quite nicely as long as you're using just the `qplot` function. If you wanted to do something more fancy, then it is probably easier to just write the R code as a string and call `R.eval`. To do that you need:

```
// Helper function to make calling 'eval' easier
let eval (text:string) =
  R.eval(R.parse(namedParams ["text", text ]))

eval("library(\"ggplot2\")")

// Assuming we have dataframe 'ohlc' with 'Date' and 'Open'
eval("""
  print(
    ggplot(ohlc, aes(x=Date, y=Open)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_smooth()
  )
  """)
```

I also spent some time figuring out how to pass data from F# to R (i.e. create R data frame based on data from F#, like a CSV type provider). So, to populate the `ohlc` data frame, I used this (where `SampleData` is a CSV provider for Yahoo):

```
let df =
  [ "Date",  box [| for r in SampleData.msftData -> r.Date |]
    "Open",  box [| for r in SampleData.msftData -> r.Open |]
    "High",  box [| for r in SampleData.msftData -> r.High |]
    "Low",   box [| for r in SampleData.msftData -> r.Low |]
    "Close", box [| for r in SampleData.msftData -> r.Close |] ]
  |> namedParams
  |> R.data_frame
R.assign("ohlc", df)
```

Comment: There is a blog about plotting with ggplot and F# RProvider from [evelinag](http://evelinag.com/blog/2015/12-03-using-ggplot2-from-f/#.WMpIcWxPoUQ)

Answer (score 3):

As Tomas points out, you need to print the result for ggplot2 to display anything.

We achieve this by adding a printer to the fsi session in our standard F# interactive startip script:

```
fsi.AddPrinter(fun (sexp: RDotNet.SymbolicExpression) -> sexp.Print())
```

This makes the RProvider much more useful because it prints the result of every operation in the same way as it would be printed in R.